# How to push without use git's command

Tags: linux, git

After merging one branch into another, (like develop into master) with
`git merge --no-ff develop`

If you execute the git command `git status` in a terminal just after you will see:

```
 On branch master
 Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commits.
   (use "git push" to publish your local commit)
 
 nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Which is not much different from that (if we look without paying attention):

```
 On branch master
 nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Sometimes I do not pay much attention and I forget to push. So is there an command to know if we must push? or a way to color the `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commits.` part in red?

or may be just a command that return 0 or 1 if we need to push, if yes I could include it with an `echo` routine in a git alias to make my `git status` more explicit.

Comment: Honestly, the output you were seeing `Your branch is ahead of ...` is basically the output you would get from running `git status`.  `git status` is typically what you would use to find out the state of your local branch versus the remote (or at least the version of the remote you have locally).

Comment: `git status | grep "Your branch is ahead" && git push`? You can also have the repo status shown in your shell prompt, you'll have to look up appropriate instructions based on the shell you're using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes; but when you use it in a terminal both output are in blank and in 2-3 line, it's easy to don't make the difference

Comment: @jonrsharpe I even not think about it, it should fix my issue.
Make a response to share to other with the same question.

Comment: Another option to keep this simple and in git is to add a git alias to do somthing like jon mentioned. Edit your global config like this: `git config --edit --global`, in the section `[alias]` (add the section if missing) add something like `st = ! git status | grep 'Your branch is ahead'`. Note the "!" tell git its a shell command so that you can use the pipe/grep... you could probably highlight this as well using text color codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved it by putting this in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    st = "!f() { git status -u;                                          \
         git status -u | grep \"Your branch is ahead\" > /dev/null       \
         && echo \"\\e[31m[WARNING]\\e[91m You need to push :)\"; }; f"
```

Like that just by performing `git st` I will be warned by a red message if I need to push.